# Strange lights appearing

Tags: light

I just recently rendered this scene:

[image]

My problems is the bright spot on the bottom-right corner. The same kind of light can be seen along the cave-wall to the right.

[Here's](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38360) the .blend file if you wanna take a look

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: I took a quick look at your blend. It does not seem to match the render you posted. There are substantial differences in the green crystal and the stalagmite/stalactite pillar near the entrance, not to mention differences in the placement of the mushrooms. Have I made a mistake, or was there another version of the blend you could post?

Comment: Sorry about that, I must have forgotten some setting on and saved. The .blend I provided will still catch those highlights, though. I'm gonna test around the sun lamp as suggested by @PaulMc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blend file that you have provided doesn't render to the image above.  It is always a good idea to pack external files into the Blend file.  However, my guess would be the sun lamp you have in there is managing to reach that part of the scene and provide some highlights on the surfaces you are getting the bright spots on.  A quick test would be to turn off the sun and see if the bright spots remain.  If they go away then you can be sure that the sun is the source.  If you still want the bright area at the rear of the scene then you may need to rotate the sun a little or change it to a point source and add a Color/Light Falloff node into the strength.

Comment: Turns out the sun lamp was the culprit. It also didn't make the scene look any better than without it, from the two renders with and without... so goodbye sun! Thanks for the help :) (that's for you, not the sun)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem feel free to 'accept' this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.